# How to load a data source to a gateway from public server postgres Database?

Tags: postgresql, odbc, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to connect data-source to PowerBI Gateway from a public virtual machine, the data source is Postgresql. I had installed gateway on the same machine and tried to connect a new data source in the web and then given all the details to connect to the server. By clicking OK I got the following error:

```
Cluster URI:    https://wabi-europe-north-b-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Status code:    400
Error Code: DMTS_PublishDatasourceToClusterErrorCode
Underlying error code:  -2147467259
Underlying error message:   The credentials provided for the Odbc source are invalid.
```

I tried using postrges data source also but the connection was not successful.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had got the connection, the mistake was from my side I had given system username and password instead of DB username and password. Now the data source is connected to the gateway.